# How to compare or Match values in 10 different columns on the same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to compare 10 columns in the same row for identical values ? also ignore empty cells.

This formula `[=if(or(a2=z2,b2=y2,c2=x2,"ok","not ok"))` gives me false positives for the empty cells. I have to make sure that the items in table 1 has the same quantities in table 2.

edited to simplify the question.. i have only 3 columns in the example but in my actual problem i have over 100 columns in each table

[image]

Comment: Compare to what? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55052477/edit) to provide sample data and expected outcome.

Comment: Please explain the logic. It's unclear to me how both shop1 and shop2 can be "OK". Looking at your formula, it looks like there is a misplaced parenthesis. try: `=if(or(a2=z2,b2=y2,c2=x2),"ok","not ok")` Maybe that's your problem

Comment: Are both table structures always exactly the same? This is regardless of the values of course.